# Does AngularFire2's database.list hold a reference or actually grab data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm following along the with the basic [AngularFire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md), and the general format seems to be:

```
const items = af.database.list('/items');
// to get a key, check the Example app below
items.update('key-of-some-data', { size: newSize });
```

My confusion is that in the source code, it seems as though calling database.list() grabs all the data at the listed url (line 114 [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/firebase_list_factory.ts))

Can anyone help clarify how that works?  If it does indeed grab all the data, is there a better way of getting a reference without doing that?  Or should I just reference each particular URL individually?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not really basic Angular 2. Those methods expose an *observable*; I expect the HTTP call is made when you *subscribe* to them (e.g. as the docs suggest using `| async` in the template). Beyond that it's unclear to me what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I meant AngularFire2.  I've updated it.  I would have thought the same in terms of subscribe vs. list, but at I noted, ref.once('value') is called in the file that I linked to on line 114

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an [AngularFire2 list](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md), it holds an internal Firebase ref - accessible via the list's public `$ref` property.

The list is an `Observable` - which serves as the interface for reading from the database - and includes some additional methods for writing to the database: `push`, `update` and `remove`.

In the code in your question, you are only calling the `update` method and are not subscribing to the observable, so no data is loaded from the database into memory:

```
const items = af.database.list('/items');
// to get a key, check the Example app below
items.update('key-of-some-data', { size: newSize });
```

It's only when a subscription to the observable is made that listeners for `value` and the `child_...` events are added to the ref and the list builds and maintains an internal array that's emitted via the observable. So if you are only calling the methods that write to the database, it won't be loading any data.

The [AngularFire2 object](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md) is implemented in a similar manner.

Comment: Perfect, this answers my question.  Thanks!