# Does creating firebase Object observable in itself, hits server ? (without subscribing)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angular2-observables

I was wondering whether following statement in itself,(angular4 + firebase) trigger a server call ?

```
this.fireDB.object('/users/uid')
```

And from above curiosity. If I have

```
user = this.fireDB.object('/users/id').take(1)
shopOwners = this.fireDB.object('/shops/id').take(1)
user.concat(shopOwners).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

..will there be 2 hits to server even if a 'user' with 'id' exists ?

Comment: you can see in developer tools - network tab XHR?

Comment: Nothing in XHR, but in WS tabs, I  see request only when I subscribe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603055/6680611